# Finding a cluster with python

Tags: python, datagrid, grid, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I'd like to ask you to point me in a direction where I can use proper tools and functions for my problem. I have a large grid of cells (200k+) and each cell has an index and a certain value, e.g. a certain cell has `ID=2050` and `value=5500`.

What I want to do is to find a group(s) of cells, which SUM of values matches a certain criteria, e.g. `SUMvalues = 15000` given the condition of distance between cells, which means the conditions must take into account two variables: distance between centroids and values of cells.

Two cells next to each other can suffice the condition, but what if there are some nonadjacent cells, like on the image below?
I am looking at the tutorials for Clustering With K-Means in Python, but i don't feel quite optimistic just yet. Do you have any other suggestions?

[image: Cluster example]

e

Comment: Not quite optimistic regarding what? That it could work? With k-means you have to set the number of clusters before, not by some certain value in their neighbourhood. You could use a 2d convolution with a growing circular kernel, but this would only consider circular clusters well. I would start with k-means with a for loop over the number of clusters and check them using your sum criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This is a constraint optimization problem, not a clustering problem. K-means etc. will *not* allow you to specify a value constraint.

Properly formulate the objective function (what is acceptably close) and constraints (value limit), and try approaching it with a solver for such problems.

Usually these are NP hard, so you can only afford to find a good, but not the best solution. Greedy strategies are desirable to reduce the runtime.